# Downloading files within a QCoreApplication

Tags: c++, qt, http, c++11

I work in a team to develop a QT Application with c++. Among other things, the app needs to download files from the internet. Here is the code I wrote to download files:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
        QNetworkAccessManager man;
        std::string urlc = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg"; //Ramdom svg file
        QUrl url(QString::fromStdString(urlc));
        QNetworkRequest req(url);
        QNetworkReply* reply = man.get(req);
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [department, region, &reply](){
            QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
            QString savefile = QString::fromStdString("file.png");
            QFile out(savefile);
            out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            out.write(read);
            out.close();
            reply->close();
            reply->deleteLater();
            app.quit();
        });
        return app.exec();
  }
```

The above code works well and downloads the file at the specified url. However, if I try to extract the downloading of files to a separate function (see code below), the program doesn't work. In fact, it never even starts downloading the file.

```
std::string download_file(){
    QNetworkAccessManager man;
    std::string urlc = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg"; //Ramdom svg file
    QUrl url(QString::fromStdString(urlc));
    QNetworkRequest req(url);
    QNetworkReply* reply = man.get(req);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [department, region, &reply](){
        QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
        QString savefile = QString::fromStdString("file.png");
        QFile out(savefile);
        out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        out.write(read);
        out.close();
        reply->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
    });
    return "file.png";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    std::string path = download_file();
    std::cout << path << std::endl;

    return app.exec();
}
```

What can be the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: scope of variables, local variables, etc

Comment: @eyllanesc What do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The download is asynchronous - in effect, it's performed while `app.exec()` is running. The `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkRequest` instances must be kept alive while the download is in progress. This happens in your first example, but in your second, they are local variables in a function, and are destroyed as soon as the function returns, canceling the network operation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that QNetworkAccessManager has a greater scope in the first case, as opposed to the second case, which is only a local variable, so it will be destroyed at the attempt. One way to solve is to create a class that handles all the logic:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class Downloader: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Downloader(QObject *parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){
        connect(&m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Downloader::handle_finished);
    }
    void download(const QUrl & url, const QString & filename){
        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::User, filename);
        m_manager.get(request);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void finished(bool);
private:
    void handle_finished(QNetworkReply *reply){
        bool ok = false;
        if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
            QByteArray read = reply->readAll();
            QString filename = reply->request().attribute(QNetworkRequest::User).toString();
            QFile out(filename);
            if(out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
                out.write(read);
                out.close();
                ok = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << reply->error() << reply->errorString();
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
        Q_EMIT finished(ok);
    }
    QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Downloader downloader;

    QObject::connect(&downloader, &Downloader::finished, [](bool sucess){
        qDebug() << "download" << sucess;
    });

    downloader.download(QUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg"), "file.svg");

    return a.exec();
}
```